# How to sync React with pure JS class service

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'd like to use refs to class services inside React and the problem is sync between React and Service values updates.

My approach is to use "update" function after every data update in Service, which trigger re-render of React components where created context is used. In general it works and should work even in memo components but I wonder if I missed something.

Expected result is to use this approach without issues related to components re-rendering and live data updates across application.

I wonder if this approach is correct and will not cause unexpected errors. In basic terms this method works, but I wonder if there is a better approach

```
  class ValuesService {
    private values: string[]
    private update: () => void

    constructor({update}) {
      this.values = []
      this.update = update
    }

    setValues(values: string[]) {
      this.values = values
      this.update()
    }

    getValues() {
      return this.values
    }

  }

  const Context = createContext()

  function ExampleProvider({children}) {
    const [time, setTime] = useState(new Date());

    const update = () => {
      setTime(new Date());
    };

    const { current: values } = useRef(new ValuesService({ update }));
    
    return (
      <Context.Provider value={{time, values}}>{children}</Context.Provider>
    )
  }
```

Comment: "Do you think I can go this way? What kind of issues I can expect? What is other option to sync React with class services refs?" This is a pretty broad question.  I would suggest more focus if you want a good answer.

Comment: Do you really need this class? This class has the same functionality like `useState` - storing data and providing a function to update data on top triggers rerendering.
My suggestion is removing your time `useState`, add an `useState` for your `values` and use the value and the update function of the useState hook as ´value`  in your Provider.

Answer (score 1):

Forcing a re-render is usually not a clean solution.

State (aka. "values") that need to be used inside React components (or hooks), need to be **managed by React**. There are not many exceptions.

So in general, extracting some logic into a plain-javascript class will **not make your code cleaner** in React,
you will always have to write some kind of "React to js-class interface",
which often ends up as large as the class itself.

If your intention is to write a service that manages state, then you should **write a React hook** instead of a plain-javascript class.
You probably have to map every value to a React state anyway at some point.

If you have no choice. e.g. because it's a very large, or legacy, or external js-class, then you should/need to connect/map it to React properly
*(see "Map the value to a React state" below)*.

### Forcing update

If you really need to force an update, you should **use a counter** instead of a Date, because that is guaranteed to have a different value on every call,
while the Date might not: A value could theoretically be changed more often than once in one millisecond.
*(See also the example on [reactjs, hooks-faq: "is there something like forceupdate ?"](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-forceupdate))*.

As there is **no inherent relation** between the "force update" state and any value that you actually use,
you need to make sure yourself that the update function is called exactly once whenever a changed value will be ready to be used by any react component.

There is (might be in the future) still a potential problem:
React guarantees that every value (that is managed by React) will always be up-to-date where it is needed. React doesn't guarantee that *all* components
will be re-rendered. You are passing the `time` to the Provider, in order to make all components below re-render,
but (I believe) you can't rely on that, unless you are also using the `time` value inside every component.
I believe it will work fine for now, but theoretically React might find a way to avoid re-renders of individual components
if none of the values that are actually used have changed.

### Map the value to a React state

A better approach would be to set some React state to a value that you actually need. That way you can rely on the guarantees that React makes.
In essence, you would map (duplicate) each relevant value from your service to a React state.

Details depend on the use case. If you have many values, you might want to create one state for each of them (`useState( value1 )`), or only one state
containing an object with all values (`useState({ value1, value2, ... })`).

You may want to pass the value to the `onUpdated` callback:

```
setValues( values: string[] ){
    this.values = values;
    this.onUpdated( values );
}
```

Then you can directly "map" the value to a state:

```
const useMyService = function(){
    const [ myServicesValue, setMyServicesValue ] = useState( null );

    const myService = useMemo( () => {
        return new ValuesService({ update: setMyServicesValue } );
    }, []);
    
    return [ myServicesValue, myService.setValue ]; 
}
```

### Note: Redundant instances

You are creating a redundant instance of `ValuesService` on every execution of `ExampleProvider` in the line:

```
const { current: values } = useRef(new ValuesService({ update }));
```

These redundant instances are ignored by React, but in gerneral, calling constructors (or any other function) might waste CPU time, or even cause side effects.
*(As opposed to creating redundant functions, which also should be avoided if possible, but doesn't cost much and is pretty common in react.
Like your `const update = () ...`.)*

You could use a [`useMemo`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo) instead of a [`useRef`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef).

```
const myService = useMemo(() => {
    return new ValuesService({
        update: () => {
            setTime(new Date());
        }}
    );
}, []);
```

### Note: "onUpdated"

Btw.: You should name the callback function "onUpdated" or "onChanged" or similar, instead of "update",
because the name should reflect the fact that the value is changed and ready to be used,
not that you can update the value using this function (imagine the service would be asynchronous).